# Help: Play MovieClip at variable speed using setInterval()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to play through a MovieClip frame by frame using setInterval. Overall I'm trying to imitate speeding up and slowing down of the MovieClip by changing the setInterval time.

Basically, when a user moves the Slider the MovieClip needs to speed up or slow down based on the Slider value.

EDIT: The code above works to a certain extent. As in the slider updates updateClip() and the MovieClip does actually play at one speed. But the MovieClip does not play at the speed variable value. If I remove the ClearInterval() the MovieClip just plays at one speed but then doubles when the Slider is changed. What I'm looking for is the MovieClip to play at the same rate as speed value.

Sorry, if I'm not making sense. I'm not much of a Flash guy.

---

**EDIT: Final Version Update (Thanks for the great help everyone)**

```
// Import classes
import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.controls.SliderDirection;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

// Set variables and types
var slow:Number=0;
var speed:Number=0;
var update:Number=0;
var frame:Number=0;
var timer:Timer=null;

// Add event listener to slider
hand_control.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, updateClip);

function updateClip(e:SliderEvent):void {

    // Set frame to slider value
    frame=e.target.value;

    // Update hanle movie clip
    handle_motion_small_mc.gotoAndStop(frame);
    handle_motion_large_mc.gotoAndStop(frame);

    // Set timer if not set
    if (timer==null) {
        setTimer();
        trace('Timer is null');
    }

    // Invert slider value
    update=70-frame;

    // Output values for debugging
    trace('Actual Speed: ' + update);
    trace('Chosen Speed: ' + frame);

}

// Set and start timer
function setTimer() {
    timer=new Timer(update,1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, updateGrass);
    timer.start();
}

// Update grass movie speed
function updateGrass( ev:TimerEvent ) {
    var current:Number=grass_mc.currentFrame+1;
    grass_mc.gotoAndStop(current);
    setTimer();
}
```

Comment: so you already posted your solution? or do you mean your code doesn't work as expected (how?)

Comment: Sorry schellmax, I've made an EDIT to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine as long as it works. 
I do have a couple of suggestions that might help:

1. You might want to use a Timer instead of setInterval, as it gives you a few handy extra options.
2. Try to stay away from copy and paste code, follow [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Let's break this down into it's parts:
 - the original frame rate (frames per second ratio )
 - an arbitrary movie clip (which has **n** frames)
 - a variable to update playback

The idea is simple, you have to update the current frame of your movie clip based on a variable. You can either use that variable to control the update frequency(your interval), or
to control a variable which keeps track of your dynamic frame.

Here's an example on how you would control the time/interval:

```
var metro:Number = 1000/stage.frameRate;//'metronome' - convert fps to millis
slider.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, sliderUpdate);//slider values must be > 0 (e.g. 0.01)
var updater:Timer = new Timer(metro);
updater.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, frameUpdate);
updater.start();

function frameUpdate(event:TimerEvent):void {
    clip.gotoAndStop(updater.currentCount%clip.totalFrames);//loop at total frames (a frame variable + if(frame > totalFrame) might be faster
}
function sliderUpdate(event:Event):void{
    updater.delay = metro / slider.value;
}
```

So, the movie clips doesn't get updated all the time, you control that with a variable updated by the slider. Notice that the frame rate is converted from the 'frame measure unit'  to milliseconds.

Here is a modified version which takes into account negative and zero values for the slider:

```
var metro:Number = 1000/stage.frameRate;
slider.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, sliderUpdate);
var updater:Timer = new Timer(metro);
updater.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, frameUpdate);
updater.start();

function frameUpdate(event:TimerEvent):void {//if it's negative value - go backwards/subtract from total
    clip.gotoAndStop(slider.value < 0 ? (clip.totalFrames-updater.currentCount%clip.totalFrames) : updater.currentCount%clip.totalFrames);
}
function sliderUpdate(event:Event):void{//watchout for 0 value
    updater.delay = metro / Math.abs(slider.value == 0 ? 0.001 : slider.value);
}
```

With this approach, you would update your clip independent of any other enterframe loop you might have.

Here is a rough example of how you update based on frame, rather than time:

```
var frame:Number = 0,roundFrame:Number;
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameUpdate);
function frameUpdate(event:Event):void {
    frame += slider.value;
    roundFrame = Math.floor(Math.abs(frame))%clip.totalFrames;
    if(slider.value > 0) clip.gotoAndStop(roundFrame);  
    else                 clip.gotoAndStop(clip.totalFrames-roundFrame);
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your help George. Greatly appreciated. I did have a go at implementing your second example. However my MovieClip doesn't seem to update? [http://snipt.org/woggk](http://snipt.org/woggk)

Comment: @Danny Croft Hmmm, I've tested and it works fine. Do you have a stop() on the first frame of your grass_mc ? Do you get sliderUpdate traces ? Have a look here: http://lifesine.eu/so/frameControl.zip

Answer (score 1):

When working with ActionScript 3, you should use the [Timer](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_the_timer_class_in_actio.html) class instead of setInterval.

```
// add imports

import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

//  add to variable declarations

var timer : Timer = null;

//  this goes instead of clearInterval and setInterval, after you've set "speed"

if (timer == null) setTimer();

//  and here is the function

function setTimer() 
{
    timer = new Timer (speed, 1);
    timer.addListener (TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, updateGrass);
    timer.start();
}
//  and the updateGrass method

function updateGrass( ev:TimerEvent ) 
{
    if (grass_mc.currentFrame>249) grass_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
    else grass_mc.nextFrame();
    setTimer();
}
```

Comment: Thanks weltraumpirat, especially for including my variable names and the commenting.  I did try to implement this solution and it does work, but the MovieClip only plays (one frame then stops) when I move the Slider. What I'm trying to achieve is the MoveClip 'plays' at the rate of the speed variable e.g. Imitating speeding up and slowing down the MovieClip. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: It does.  I forgot about re-setting the timer, sorry.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you again weltraumpirat, but the MovieClip just seems to speed up no matter what value the speed variable has? It doesn't seem to slow down at all.

Comment: Check your calculations of `speed`.  The clip updates according to what is set there.

Answer (score 0):

Timer is terrible idea for time intervals less than hundreds of milliseconds. I would use `ENTER_FRAME` event and `getTimer` to get current time in milliseconds, then control clip manually with `stop()` and `nextFrame()`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with alxx -- using Timer seems classy, but I think an ENTER_FRAME approach is better, especially if you want to run your MovieClip faster than the SWF's frame rate.  I wrote a blog post about how I did it: http://www.eqsim.com/blog/?p=329.